# VSCode snippet, how to force the starting column of a line?

Tags: cobol, vscode-snippets

as cobol dev, I have to start comments at a certain column in the code.

I would like to know if there's a way to tell "for this line, start at column 7" to VSCode with snippets

I didn't find how to do.

Maybe is there an opposite of the `\t` ? It would at least be better than nothing

### EDIT :

I couldn't find anything about it. I had to create a new issue on the VSCode GitHub

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/205668

Comment: One method is to press the space bar 6 times and then type the comment.  If you're starting in column 8, try pressing the Backspace key.

Comment: I created my snippets spaces manually, so I have to be in the right column to insert it.
I would like to avoid it. insert the snippet no matter where I am and still getting the code with a good indentation

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the COBOL VSCode extensions.  The one that I use, bitlang.cobol, knows how to tab between column 7, 8 and 12.  And shift tab goes to the previous tab stop.

Comment: Yes I'm using this one too. The issue here is a waste of time because when I insert a snippet I have to place my cursor at the right column or to indent correctly the block. Second problem, I made these snippets for cobol developers in the company. They are used to UltraEdit which places the snippet correctly everytime and this issue is one of the reasons they don't switch to VSCode. Don't hesitate to check the VSCode request I made, you'll quickly understand how useful it can be for the developer who makes snippets :D